# handling a set of numerical data

Tags: c#

Imagine this is the data-set you are given as an array.

> 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17,12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17,17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12

As you can see there are two sets with the number 17, what algorithm can I use to sum the first set of 17s and another sum for the second set of 17s.

So i want two variables that hold the sums of the two sets of 17s which are separated by one set of 12s, what algorithm would achieve that?

**So the expected outcome would be like this:**

1st sum = 68 (because we had 4 x 17 first time)

2nd sum = 119 (because we had 7 x 17 second time)

Comment: This is the kind of thing where people expect you to show what you've tried.

Comment: i think you need to specify the problem more too. Are we always summing 17s? if the input was 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, be 0 since there are no 17s?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to keep track of the number/sum pairs in a `Tuple<int, int>`, and populate a list of these by walking through the array and adding/updating the items as you go:

```
var input = new[] {12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12,
    12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12};

var results = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
Tuple<int, int> current = null;

foreach (var number in input)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        current = new Tuple<int, int>(number, number);
    }
    else if (current.Item1 == number)
    {
        current = new Tuple<int, int>(number, current.Item2 + number);
    }
    else
    {
        results.Add(current);
        current = new Tuple<int, int>(number, number);
    }
}

results.Add(current);
```

Then the results would look something like:

```
// To show just the groups of '17', we can do:
Console.Write("Group sums where the number is '17': ");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results.Where(t => t.Item1 == 17).Select(t => t.Item2)));

// Or just write out all the groups:
Console.WriteLine($"All groups (num, sum): {string.Join(", ", results)}");
GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
```

Output

[image: image of console output for above code]

Comment: Using the new [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) with named items would be more speaking. `var results = new List<(int num, int sum)>();` or even declare a simple struct.

Answer (score 1):

You could user an *iterator method*, it's fairly neat. It will also allow for unlimited groups:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> DoStuff(IEnumerable<int> source, int target)
{
   var sum = 0;
   foreach (var item in source)
      if (item == target)
         sum += item; 
      else if (sum > 0)
      {
         yield return sum;
         sum = 0;
      }

   if (sum > 0) 
      yield return sum;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = new[] {12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12};
var results = DoStuff(input, 17);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", results));
```

**Output**

```
68
119
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that, so here is one for you: iterate thru the array and count things, so you can get something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp22
{
    public class Pair
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int Sum { get; set; }

        public Pair(int val, int sum)
        {
            Value = val;
            Sum = sum;
        }
        public void AddToSum(int x)
        {
            Sum += x;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Value: {Value}, Sum: {Sum}";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 };
            var list = new List<Pair>();

            var pair = new Pair(array[0], array[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int current = array[i];
                int previous = array[i - 1];
                if (current != previous)
                {
                    list.Add(pair);
                    pair = new Pair(current, current);
                }
                else
                {
                    pair.AddToSum(current);
                }
            }

            print(list);

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void print(List<Pair> list)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Please note: the assumption is an array size > 1.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[]
        {
            12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 
            17, 17, 17,12, 12, 12, 12, 
            12, 17, 17, 17, 17,17, 17, 
            17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12
        };

        var result = SpecialSum(data, 17).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> SpecialSum(int[] data, int target)
    {
        var group = 0;
        var number = new int?();
        return data.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            number = number ?? x;
            if (x != number)
            {
                number = x;
                group++;
            }
            return (group, number);
        }).Where(x => x.Key.number == target)
          .Select(x => x.Sum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make things clearer, by creating a new type.

```
struct NumberSet
{
    public NumberSet(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
        Sum = number; // Always begin with the first number added.
    }

    public int Number { get; } // Cannot be changed later.
    public int Sum { get; private set; }

    public void Increment() => Sum += Number; // Don't need a parameter. The Number is known.

    public override string ToString() => $"Number = {Number}, Sum = {Sum}";
}
```

The algorithm:

```
var input = new int[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 };

var sets = new List<NumberSet>();
int i = 0;
while (i < input.Length) {
    var currentSet = new NumberSet(input[i]);
    while (++i < input.Length && input[i] == currentSet.Number) {
        currentSet.Increment();
    }
    sets.Add(currentSet);
}
```

Console output:

```
foreach (NumberSet numberSet in sets) {
    Console.WriteLine(numberSet); // ToString() is overriden, so we automatically get it right.
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

You can also filter by the number 17:

```
foreach (NumberSet numberSet in sets.Where(s => s.Number == 17)) {
    Console.WriteLine(numberSet);
}
```

Or instead of adding the sets to a list, you can print directly:

```
var input = new int[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 };

int i = 0;
while (i < input.Length) {
    var currentSet = new NumberSet(input[i]);
    while (++i < input.Length && input[i] == currentSet.Number) {
        currentSet.Increment();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(currentSet);
}
```

or filtered

```
if (currentSet.Number == 17) Console.WriteLine(currentSet);
```

As you can see from all the answers given here, there are always many ways to solve a problem.