# How to sum up numbers that are greater than or equal to 17 from two locations inside an array?

Tags: c#

I have an array with these values:

```
var values = new [] { 13, 18, 13, 12, 13, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 18, 17, 17, 12, 13, 15, 17, 16, 16, 19, 18, 19, 20, 19, 18, 16, 11, 13, 19, 14, 12 };
```

I want to sum up all elements that are greater or equal to 17. This should be done only when there is a group of elements with their values being greater or equal to 17. So if there is a standalone element with a value of 17 or greater, like the values in position 1, 16 and 28, they should be ignored and not be added to the sum.

There should be two sums and the expected result should be:

**first sum = 143** ([pos5] 17 + [pos6] 17 + [pos7] 18 + [pos8] 19 + [pos9] 20 + [pos10] 18 + [pos11] 17 + [pos12] 17)

**second sum = 145** ([pos19] 19 + [pos20] 18 + [pos21] 19 + [pos22] 20 + [pos23] 19 + [pos24] 18)

Thanks in advance

I am trying to achieve what I wish achieve with some booleans in place, however this does not work as expected. I did an if statement which sums up all elements that are greater than or equal to 17, however this just sums up all elements that are greater than or equal to 17 to one sum, when I want the program to produce sums (in this case 2 sums) for elements that are that are greater than or equal to 17 and have neighboring elements that are also that are greater than or equal to 17. I tried other things as well, however have been unsuccessful to produce the expected the outcome.

```
            if (stepIntoIf == false) {
                if (nums[i] >= 17 && nums[i + 1] < 17)
                {
                    stepIntoIf = true;
                    booleanChanger(stepIntoIf);
                    continue;
                }

            }


            if (nums[i] >= 17)
            {
                while(fisrtvisited == false)
                {
                    firstIndex = i;
                    fisrtvisited = true;
                }
                allTotal = nums[i] + allTotal;

                if (nums[i+1] < 17)
                {
                    while (secondVisited == false)
                    {
                        secondIndex = i;
                        secondVisited = true;
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: @dyukha - That doesn't match what the OP is asking for.

Comment: The second sum is incorrect - it should be `113`.

Comment: Hasn't this already been answered in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633742/handling-a-set-of-numerical-data) from two days ago?

Answer (score 0):

It's not overly pretty, but this works:

```
var values = new [] { 13, 18, 13, 12, 13, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 18, 17, 17, 12, 13, 15, 17, 16, 16, 19, 18, 19, 20, 19, 18, 16, 11, 13, 19, 14, 12 };

var extended = new [] { 0 }.Concat(values).Concat(new [] { 0 }).ToArray();

var results =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, values.Length)
        .Select(x => values.Skip(x).Take(3).ToArray())
        .Where(x => x.Length == 3)
        .Select(x => x[1] >= 17 && (x[0] >= 17 || x[2] >= 17) ? x[1] : 0)
        .Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(), (a, x) =>
        {
            if (x == 0)
                a.Add(new List<int>());
            else
                a.Last().Add(x);
            return a;
        })
        .Where(x => x.Count > 0)
        .Select(x => x.Sum())
        .ToArray();
```

That gives `143` & `113`.

Answer (score 0):

You can coalesce ranges of values >= 17 with a `GroupWhile` extension then sum the ranges whose length > 1, e.g.:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                List<T> currentList = null;
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(iterator.Current))
                    {
                        if (currentList == null)
                        {
                            currentList = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentList.Add(iterator.Current);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (currentList != null)
                        {
                            yield return currentList;
                            currentList = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currentList != null)
                {
                    yield return currentList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values = new[] {
                13, 18, 13, 12, 13, 17, 17, 18, 19, 20, 18,
                17, 17, 12, 13, 15, 17, 16, 16, 19, 18, 19,
                20, 19, 18, 16, 11, 13, 19, 14, 12
            };

            var sums = values
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupWhile(item => item >= 17)
                .Select(range => range.ToArray())
                .Where(array => array.Length > 1)
                .Select(array => array.Sum());

            foreach (var sum in sums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}", sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Sum = 143
Sum = 113
```